# Text overlap issue on Careers 2.0 profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I just came across the following text overlap problem on my Careers 2.0 profile page. It looks like the employer name is overlapping with the employment dates.

> [image]

Comment: Golly, none of my job titles + employer names were ever long enough for that to happen to me..

Comment: Assistant TO the regional manager